# Is it possible to create custom view to show every documents / file in any sub folders?

Tags: view

We have a pages library and document library. And there are some folders inside these libraries. Our user would like to have a custom view to show any pages/documents in any sub folders. Is it possible?

One more question, if we create a column to store metadata in document library (let's say region). And a file in a folder contain a metadata (region = US). If we create a custom view to filter region = US, does that file show in the custom view or not? (the folder does not tag with region metadata)

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the view, in the view settings page, scroll down and expand the "folders" category, and select the "show all items without folders" option. Optionally, scroll back up and set the filter as desired to set the region.